# Db4oTool -Excluding Class From Enhacement

Tags: extension-methods, xamarin.android, db4o

First of all this issue only happens when I run the db4oTool against an assembly taregeting the Mono For Android profile, targeting a normal .Net class library works fine.

The issue:
I am running the following command as a post build event:

**Db4oTool.exe -tp -vv -debug -collections -by-attribute:DoNotDb4OEnhance -not $(TargetPath)**

This results in the following error printed to the output window: (Full Log [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/20210444/db4oToolLog.txt))

> Entering method 'System.Int32
>   Ats.Loto.Model.EnergyTagExtensions::GetNextTagNumber(System.Collections.Generic.IList`1<Ats.Loto.Model.EnergyTag>,Ats.Loto.Model.EnergyType)'
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.
>        at Db4oTool.TA.TACollectionsStep.<TAEnabledCollectionInstantiations>b__4(Instruction
>   candidate)
>        at Db4oTool.Core.InstrumentationUtil.<Where>d__0.MoveNext()
>        at Db4oTool.TA.TACollectionsStep.InstrumentCollectionInstantiation(MethodDefinition
>   methodDefinition)
>        at Db4oTool.TA.TACollectionsStep.Process(MethodDefinition method)
>        at Db4oTool.TA.TAInstrumentation.ProcessMethod(MethodDefinition method)
>        at Db4oTool.Core.AbstractAssemblyInstrumentation.ProcessMethods(IEnumerable
>   methods)
>        at Db4oTool.Core.AbstractAssemblyInstrumentation.ProcessTypes(IEnumerable`1
>   types, Predicate`1 filter, Action`1 action)
>        at Db4oTool.Core.AbstractAssemblyInstrumentation.ProcessAssembly()
>        at Db4oTool.Core.AbstractAssemblyInstrumentation.Run(InstrumentationContext
>   context)
>        at Db4oTool.Core.InstrumentationPipeline.Run()
>        at Db4oTool.Program.RunPipeline(ProgramOptions options)
>        at Db4oTool.Program.Run(ProgramOptions options)
>        at Db4oTool.Program.Main(String[] args)

If I remove the -collections attribute it will work.  I try to exclude the "EnergyTagExtensions" class with the

**-by-attribute:DoNotDb4OEnhance -not**

switches but it either has no effect or I'm doing it wrong.

Below is the class that I think is causing the db4otool to be unhappy based on the log.

```
[DoNotDb4OEnhance]
public static class EnergyTagExtensions
{
    public static int GetNextTagNumber(this IList<EnergyTag> source, EnergyType activeEnergyType)
    {
        if (source.Count == 0)
            return 1;

        var concernedTags =
            source.Where(c => c.TagId != null && c.TagId.StartsWith(activeEnergyType.Prefix)).OrderBy(
                c => c.TagIndex).ToList();

        if (!concernedTags.Any())
            return 1;

        return (concernedTags.Max(c => c.TagIndex) + 1);
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how to get this working? Thanks in advance for any insight.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding Db4oTool not "respecting" the filter, the problem is that you need to enter the attribute's fully qualified name.

Also note that you cannot omit *Attribute* from the attribute name (I assume that you have followed .Net best practices and named your attribute like **DoNotDb4OEnhanceAttribute**)

I just filled an [issue](http://tracker.db4o.com/browse/COR-2275) to improve Db4oTool documentation.

Regarding the *NullReferenceException*, I'll try to reproduce but if I fail to, can you send me, privately, a small sample assembly that reproduces it?

**EDIT - Mar/01/2012**

I checked Monodroid documentation and found that [Func<T, TResult>](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=T%3aSystem.Func%602) is indeed defined in mscorlib (on Monodroid), so probably Db4oTool is looking up types in the wrong assembly

Comment: I renamed my attribute to be suffixed with "Attribute" and included the fully qualified name of the parameter in the call to the db4oTool. The db4oTool still throws the same exception.  Here is the assembly I am trying to run the db4oTool against.  [link](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/20210444/M4AModel.dll)  Let me know if you want the source code as well.

Comment: strange. You did not have "Attribute" as part of your attribute name before? By "qualified name of the parameter" you mean "fully qualified name of the *attribute*", right? And no, I don't need the source code. I'll take a look in this later today

Comment: Correct, Originally I did not have "Attribute" in the attribute name but I do now.  Yes, I meant fully qualified name of the attribute, not parameter, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I am using Mono For Android version 4.0.3.  I checked for updates to the product and I am using the newest beta build.